# Symfony2 impossible to clear cache on my prod server

Tags: symfony

i've deployed my S2 Project on my remote server (nginx) and when i try to clear the cache i've got an error:

[RuntimeException]
  Unable to write in the "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Git/S2project/app/cache/prod" directory

why does it point on my local install and not on my server??

Comment: I had already have the chmod on 777 on these folder.

I fixed it by deleting what was inside my app/cache/dev and app/cache/prod folders.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have permission to write in `cache` folder, you should run this command:

```
chmod -R 777 app/cache/*
```

and same for the `logs` folder

```
chmod -R 777 app/logs/*
```

Comment: Or it's possible the owner of the cache folder be different, so he can use `chown` to change the owner

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to remove cache "manually"

`rm -rf cache/*`

and then as suggested by **ponciste**

`chmod 777 -R cache/*`

Answer (score 0):

the uname of the app.php file is not set to the right user on your prod server.